# Setting up a Styling Class in C#

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a class called Themes which keeps track of colors to be used in other classes. The class contains various different colors which changes depending on the day.

```
public class Themes
    var textColor;
    var contentColor;

    updateTheme()
    {
        updates colors
    }
```

There are 2 ways in my mind that I can access the fields.

```
theme = new Theme()
textColor = theme.textColor
```

or

```
theme = new Theme()
textColor = theme.GetTextColor()
```

The style class has at least 20 fields. I know both ways work, I'm wondering which would be better code practice. (Would it be considered ok to expose these fields and set them all as public? or write 20 GetMethods?)

Comment: Why aren't you using properties?  Also, you cannot have a class field declared as `var`, that would not compile.

Comment: If you're just returning a value, use a property. If you're executing code that does something, write a Get method. What you want is a readonly property: `public Color TextColor { get; private set; }`. In either case, it's recommended to terminate your statements with semicolons.

Comment: **Auto-Property** example: `public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: @maccettura i'm not actually using var, it's pseudocode

Comment: @lost9123193 Ah, well Ed has already answered your question.  The fields should be [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead if they are just storing values.

Comment: @maccettura oh ok i'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Does the theme class return the same color value for a property for all clients? In otherwords, perhaps this class should be static?

Comment: @RufusL I have a method in the class that updates the fields and changes the theme colors depending on the time of day. So the colors do change

Comment: Yes, but I was asking if they change consistently for all clients who access the class? In otherwords, if client 1 asks for the TextColor and client 2 asks for the TextColor, will they always get the same value?

Comment: @RufusL the text colors will be different values depending on the time of day, so at 8:00AM it would be red, where at 5Pm it would be blue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first way (which appears to be using a property), but personally, I might do something like this.

```
public enum ThemeColor
{
    TextColor,
    BackgroundColor,
    // Etc.
}

public ??? GetColor(ThemeColor color)
{
    // Return the requested color here
}
```

While this is a little more verbose.

```
textColor = theme.GetColor(ThemeColor.TextColor);
```

It could make your implementation more simple. For example, maybe your colors are stored in an array or a `List<>`. So you could just convert the enum to an integer that efficiently serves as an index into your array. Much simpler that writing twenty methods or properties.

I also find this approach quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

The language feature you should use is properties.  These syntactically look like fields to consuming code, but you can implement custom logic for getting or setting values in the implementation.  You can also restrict them to be readonly or writeonly (very uncommon).

See the Microsoft C# programming guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Syntax is like this to write:

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo(int bar, string baz) {
        Bar = bar;
        Baz = baz;
    }

    public int Bar { get; set; } //Read/write property

    public string Baz { get; } //Readonly

    public bool IsFooEven {
       get { return Bar % 2 == 0; } //Calculated property
    }
}
```

Consumers would just see this:

```
var foo = new Foo(5, "abc");

var bar = foo.Bar; //returns 5

var baz = foo.Baz; //returns "abc"

foo.Baz = "xyz"; //sets value
```

Properties are actually implemented as a `get_Bar()` and `set_Bar(int value)` method around a field in the compiled assembly, but C# makes them nicer to use.